# View SOAP message body generated by WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

How to view SOAP message to check the IsWrapped in MessageContract attribute, as the example below:

```
[MessageContract]
public class HelloGreetingMessage
{
  private string localGreeting;

  [MessageBodyMember(
    Name = "Salutations", 
    Namespace = "http://www.examples.com"
  )]
  public string Greeting
  {
    get { return localGreeting; }
    set { localGreeting = value; }
  }
}
```

**How to view this:**

```
/*
 The following is the request message, edited for clarity.

  <s:Envelope>
    <s:Header>
      <!-- Note: Some header content has been removed for clarity.
      <a:Action>http://GreetingMessage/Action</a:Action> 
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1"></a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body u:Id="_0" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <HelloGreetingMessage xmlns="Microsoft.WCF.Documentation">
        <Salutations xmlns="http://www.examples.com">Hello.</Salutations>
      </HelloGreetingMessage>
    </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
 */
```

Comment: See [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use tools like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [FireShark](http://fireshark.org/) to inspect your request and response. You can also debug Https traffic.

Comment: This works great. The trace file for me didn't have the soap message in for some reason.